# How to format output of Multiple Pssession Results to include a space between each computername

Tags: powershell, formatting, output, invoke-command

Maybe this is simpler than I think but i was not able to find an answer on the web based on my searches.

I have created a function that gets a list of computer names from a file and stores them in variable to use to create new pssession and connect to all the machines then use invoke-command to run get-childitem on the users directory and get all the user directories on each machine.  I then use select on the scriptblock to just select the directory name,lastwritetime,and the computername.  This outputs to a table with the 3 columns and works fine.  I have the results stored in a variable and just output it to a file.  My question is, is there a way i can easily group the results based on machine name?  I want the output to comeback with a space for new line for each computer.  What i get now is all the machines results together.  I know if i use a foreach loop and invoke-command for each computer the output would be separated but for a lot of machines enumerating each one would take some time. Here is an example of what i have as output:

```
UserDirectory   LastWriteTime   ComputerName
USer1           1/2/2020 13:50  Computer14
User6           1/2/2020 13:15  Computer14
User8           9/25/2019 17:14 Computer14
User3           8/29/2019 11:17 Computer14
User1           1/2/2020 13:50  Computer02
User6           1/2/2020 13:15  Computer02
User8           9/25/2019 17:14 Computer02
User1           1/2/2020 13:50  Computer05
User6           1/2/2020 13:15  Computer05
User2           12/21/2019 3:23 Computer05
User7           10/24/2019 10:13Computer05
User8           9/25/2019 17:14 Computer05
User6           1/2/2020 13:55  Computer15
User1           1/2/2020 13:50  Computer15
User4           11/9/2019 11:36 Computer15
User8           10/5/2019 21:10 Computer15
```

This is the output  i would prefer to have.

```
UserDirectory   LastWriteTime   ComputerName
USer1           1/2/2020 13:50  Computer14
User6           1/2/2020 13:15  Computer14
User8           9/25/2019 17:14 Computer14
User3           8/29/2019 11:17 Computer14

User1           1/2/2020 13:50  Computer02
User6           1/2/2020 13:15  Computer02
User8           9/25/2019 17:14 Computer02

User1           1/2/2020 13:50  Computer05
User6           1/2/2020 13:15  Computer05
User2           12/21/2019 3:23 Computer05
User7           10/24/2019 10:13Computer05
User8           9/25/2019 17:14 Computer05

User6           1/2/2020 13:55  Computer15
User1           1/2/2020 13:50  Computer15
User4           11/9/2019 11:36 Computer15
User8           10/5/2019 21:10 Computer15
```

Comment: AFAIK There's no built-in way to achieve what you're asking for. You would have to create it by yourself. You could try to use `Group-Object` to split your results into logical chunks and output them in a kind of seperated chunks

Answer (score 0):

Got It working using group-object.  Probably not the best way to do it but it works.

```
$test = $results | group-Object Computername
$hash = $results | group-Object Computername -AsHashTable -AsString

foreach ($name in $test.name){
      $hash.$name + ''
}
```